# Google Sheets conditional formatting with differently styled dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, count, cell, conditional-formatting

in Google Sheets I'd like to format an area of cells automatically by comparing its date value to another cell. In fact, I have some cells representing a month (the area of cells to be formatted) and a single cell with another date (05.05.2022 formatted as 05.05. see screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

So date for homework is located in U6 and cell area for moth of may is K11:Q16. When I set conditional formatting to

`apply to range: K11:Q16`

and

`Date is: exact date: =U6` or `custom formula is: =U6`

it does not work. But when I set range to N12 (05.05.2022 formatted as 5) it does work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

edit:
I created a separate sheet for sharing, so this does not fit to the screenshot:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gBx3dbzxk3Qb999uo3YMdz0A9-ViSE4xPeihhasN7FQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: pls share a spreadsheet to investigate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=COUNTIF($I$2:$I$5; D11)
```

or:

```
=MATCH(D11; $I$2:$I$5; )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. i guess i will have to do some research to this formulas.

Comment: Yes it did although I do not really know why :D

Comment: @elvistheking see: https://productivityspot.com/highlight-duplicates-google-sheets/